# iOS bar button icon image sometimes missing

Tags: ios, image, user-interface

I have weird problem with iOS 8 application: there is a bar button image with some icon. 
Problem is that the icon is sometimes shown, but sometimes is missing (but item remains clickable - without any visible appearance, I just know it's there, so I know where to click).

I haven't seen any pattern that would suggest where could be problem, it just disappears and appears randomly.

Anyone had similar problem?

I have the problem in simulator and on device.

Comment: where did you assign the image to button? do u have sample code?

Comment: In the Interface Builder, so nothing in code..

Comment: Did you assign to navigationitem or navigation bar is there any screen shot?

Answer (score 0):

Check,

1. if the name of your image that you put with your button is same with the targeted image files you put in your assets files
2. Check the view layers. You might put the image button layer under some other view that block your button image